# How to determine best parameters and best score for each scoring metric in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am trying to evaluate multiple scoring metrics to determine the best parameters for model performance. i.e., to say:

> To maximize F1, I should use these parameters. To maximize precision, I
> should use these parameters.

I am working off the following example from [this sklearn page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multimetric-scoring)

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.datasets import make_hastie_10_2
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

X, y = make_hastie_10_2(n_samples=5000, random_state=42)


scoring = {'PRECISION': 'precision', 'F1': 'f1'}

gs = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42),
                  param_grid={'min_samples_split': range(2, 403, 10)},
                  scoring=scoring, refit='F1', return_train_score=True)
gs.fit(X, y)
best_params = gs.best_params_
best_estimator = gs.best_estimator_

print(best_params)
print(best_estimator)
```

Which yields:

```
{'min_samples_split': 62}
DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=62, random_state=42)
```

However, what I would be looking for would be to find these results **for each metric**, so in this case, for *F1* and *precision*

How can I achieve getting the best parameters for each type of scoring metric in `GridSearchCV`?

Note - I believe it has something to do with my usage of `refit='F1'`, but am not sure how to use multiple metrics there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do so, you'll have to dig into the detailed results of the whole grid search CV procedure; fortunately, these detailed results are returned in the `cv_results_` attribute of the `GridSearchCV` object ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)).

I have rerun your code as-is, but I am not retyping it here; it suffices to say that, despite explicitly setting the random number generator's seed, I am getting a different final result (I guess due to different versions) as:

```
{'min_samples_split': 322}
DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                       max_depth=None, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=322,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                       random_state=42, splitter='best')
```

but this is not important for the issue at hand here.

The easiest way to use the returned `cv_results_` dictionary is to convert it to a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
cv_results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gs.cv_results_)
```

Still, as it includes too much info (columns), I will further simplify it here to demonstrate the issue (feel free to explore it more fully yourself):

```
df = cv_results[['params', 'mean_test_PRECISION', 'rank_test_PRECISION', 'mean_test_F1', 'rank_test_F1']]

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
                        params  mean_test_PRECISION  rank_test_PRECISION  mean_test_F1  rank_test_F1
0     {'min_samples_split': 2}             0.771782                    1      0.763041            41
1    {'min_samples_split': 12}             0.768040                    2      0.767331            38
2    {'min_samples_split': 22}             0.767196                    3      0.776677            29
3    {'min_samples_split': 32}             0.760282                    4      0.773634            32
4    {'min_samples_split': 42}             0.754572                    8      0.777967            26
5    {'min_samples_split': 52}             0.754034                    9      0.777550            27
6    {'min_samples_split': 62}             0.758131                    5      0.773348            33
7    {'min_samples_split': 72}             0.756021                    6      0.774301            30
8    {'min_samples_split': 82}             0.755612                    7      0.768065            37
9    {'min_samples_split': 92}             0.750527                   10      0.771023            34
10  {'min_samples_split': 102}             0.741016                   11      0.769896            35
11  {'min_samples_split': 112}             0.740965                   12      0.765353            39
12  {'min_samples_split': 122}             0.731790                   13      0.763620            40
13  {'min_samples_split': 132}             0.723085                   14      0.768605            36
14  {'min_samples_split': 142}             0.713345                   15      0.774117            31
15  {'min_samples_split': 152}             0.712958                   16      0.776721            28
16  {'min_samples_split': 162}             0.709804                   17      0.778287            24
17  {'min_samples_split': 172}             0.707080                   18      0.778528            22
18  {'min_samples_split': 182}             0.702621                   19      0.778516            23
19  {'min_samples_split': 192}             0.697630                   20      0.778103            25
20  {'min_samples_split': 202}             0.693011                   21      0.781047            10
21  {'min_samples_split': 212}             0.693011                   21      0.781047            10
22  {'min_samples_split': 222}             0.693011                   21      0.781047            10
23  {'min_samples_split': 232}             0.692810                   24      0.779705            13
24  {'min_samples_split': 242}             0.692810                   24      0.779705            13
25  {'min_samples_split': 252}             0.692810                   24      0.779705            13
26  {'min_samples_split': 262}             0.692810                   24      0.779705            13
27  {'min_samples_split': 272}             0.692810                   24      0.779705            13
28  {'min_samples_split': 282}             0.692810                   24      0.779705            13
29  {'min_samples_split': 292}             0.692810                   24      0.779705            13
30  {'min_samples_split': 302}             0.692810                   24      0.779705            13
31  {'min_samples_split': 312}             0.692810                   24      0.779705            13
32  {'min_samples_split': 322}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
33  {'min_samples_split': 332}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
34  {'min_samples_split': 342}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
35  {'min_samples_split': 352}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
36  {'min_samples_split': 362}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
37  {'min_samples_split': 372}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
38  {'min_samples_split': 382}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
39  {'min_samples_split': 392}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
40  {'min_samples_split': 402}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
```

The names of the columns should be self-explanatory; they include the parameters tried, the score for each one of the metrics used, and the corresponding rank (`1` meaning the best). You can immediately see, for example, that, despite the fact that `'min_samples_split': 322` gives indeed the best F1 score, it is **not** the only parameter setting that does so, and there are many more settings that also give the best F1 score and a respective `rank_test_F1` of `1` in the results.

From this point, it is trivial to get the info you want; for example, here are the best models for each one of your two metrics:

```
print(df.loc[df['rank_test_PRECISION']==1]) # best precision
# result:
                     params  mean_test_PRECISION  rank_test_PRECISION  mean_test_F1  rank_test_F1
0  {'min_samples_split': 2}             0.771782                    1      0.763041            41

print(df.loc[df['rank_test_F1']==1]) # best F1
# result:
                        params  mean_test_PRECISION  rank_test_PRECISION  mean_test_F1  rank_test_F1
32  {'min_samples_split': 322}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
33  {'min_samples_split': 332}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
34  {'min_samples_split': 342}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
35  {'min_samples_split': 352}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
36  {'min_samples_split': 362}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
37  {'min_samples_split': 372}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
38  {'min_samples_split': 382}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
39  {'min_samples_split': 392}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
40  {'min_samples_split': 402}             0.688417                   33      0.782772             1
```

Comment: just for understanding's sake...this would read that `min_samples_split: 2` was the best hyperparameter for maximizing precision, even with `refit=F1`?

Comment: @wundermahn exactly; going through the `df`, you can easily confirm that the respective precision value of 0.771782 is the maximum one indeed. What you specify in `refit` determines what the process will return as `best_params` and `best_estimator`  (that's why here you got the parameters that maximize F1, and not precision), since it should be apparent that you cannot optimize for more than one metric *simultaneously*.